# Is this important to clean test data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-cleaning

In the training data, I did feature engineering and clean my data. Is this important to do the same with test data?
I know some basic modifications like label encoding, dependent/independent feature split, etc.. are required in test data as well. But do we really need to CLEAN the test data before we do the predictions?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What type of data are we talking about? What do you mean with cleaning?

Comment: Cleaning means removing outliers, filling missing values, normalize the data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer you with Yes or No so let me start with the data distribution on all of your Train/Test/Dev set.
According to Prof.Andrew ng, the Test and Dev set should come from the same distribution ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3qpIzy4MQk)), but the trainig set can come from a different distribution ([Check it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyjJ-RpQ5zQ)), and often it's a good thing to do.
Sometimes cleaning the trainig set is very useful and also applying some basic operation for speeding the training process(Like Normalization which is not cleaning), but we are talking about training data which can and should have thousands of thousands of examples, so sometimes you can't check your data manually and clean it, Because it's maybe not worthy at all;
What do I mean? well let me show you an example:

Let's say you're bulding a cat classifier (Cat or no-Cat), and you have an accuracy of 90%, which means that you've 10% Error.
after doing Error-analysis([Check it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoAxZsdw_3w)) you find out that:

1. 6% of your error is caused of misslabeled images,(No-cat images
   labeled as cat and viceversa).
2. 44% is caused of Blurry images.
3. 50% is caused by images of Big Cats labeled as cats.
   in this case all the time your will spend fixing the misslabeled images will improve your performance (0.6%) in the best scenario (Because it's 6% from the whole 10% error), so **IT'S NOT WORTHY** correcting the misslabeld data.

### I gave an example on misslabeled data, but in general I mean any type of cleaning and fixing.

**BUT cleaning** the data in the test set may be easier, and it should be done both to Test/Dev sets if it's possibile because your test set will reflect the performance of your system on the real time data.
The Operations that you mentioned in your question are not quite cleaning but used for speeding up the process of learning or make the data apprpriate for the algorithm, and applying them depends on the shape and type of the data(images, Voice Records, words..), and on the problem you're trying to solve.

in the end As an answer, I can tell you that:

- the form and shape of the data should be the same in all the three
  sets (so applying label encoding should be for the whole data, not just
  for the training data, and also for the input data used for
  prediction because it changes the shape of the output label).
- The number of features should be the same always.
- Any operation that changes the (shape, form, number of features, ...) applied to the data should be applied on every single sample that you're gonna use in your system.

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

Normalizing the data: If you normalized your training data, then yes, normalize the test data in exactly the way you normalized the training data. But be careful that you do not re-tune any parameters you tuned on the training data.

Filling missing values: idem. Treat the test data as the training data but do not re-tune any of the parameters.

Removing outliers: probably not. The aim of the test set is to make an estimate about how well your model will perform on unseen data. So removing outliers will probably not be a good idea.

In general: only do things to your test data that you can/will also do on unseen data upon applying your model.